# How to enable launching jnlp in Opera browser?

Tags: java, safari, cross-browser, opera, jnlp

I'm trying to load a java application launched via jnlp on different browsers. Firefox and IE are launching the jnlp using java web start. I need to make Safari and Opera do the same.

I'm not considering Chrome at present because I have Chrome 43 and it doesn't allow java plugins to be launched.

I need to set the MIME type association for JNLP files but can't find out how to do it. Online search is not helpful.

Comment: *"I need to set the MIME type association for JNLP files"*  That's done on the server..

Comment: @AndrewThompson, You're right. I have added the ContentType header. IE and Firefox are able to identify the file type and show a dialog where I can choose the launch application (Java Web Start in this case). Opera and Safari on the other hand are only downloading the file. How can I make them show a launch dialog or launch by default?